# Count the number of different Boolean functions of n variables belonging to a given set A. A=(S∪T_0 )∩T_1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Count the number of different Boolean functions of n variables belonging to a given set A.

A = (S∪T_0 )∩T_1

Where :

S: Class of self-dual functions

T_0: Class of functions that preserve the constant 0

T_1: Class of functions that preserve the constant 1

[attemptToSolve_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Q1p.png)
I attempted to solve this problem, but I'm unsure if I'm on the right track. Can you please advise me on the next steps or suggest an alternative method to find the solution?
(answer: 2^((2^n)-2)  )